Group in the lower central series is generated by conjugates of comutators of generators
I heard some claim which I'm not sure if true:
Let $G$ be a group, define $\gamma_0(G):=G$ and  $\gamma_n(G):=[\gamma_{n-1}(G),G]$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Which is the definition of the lower central series of $G$.
Is it true that if $G=\langle S\rangle$ for some $S\subseteq G$ then for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$\gamma_n(G)=\langle \{[s_0,...,s_n]^x\mid s_i\in S, x\in G\} \rangle.$$
Where the comutator of more than two elements defined recursively as $[a_1,...,a_n]:=[[a_1,...,a_{n-1}],a_n]$.
I succeed to prove it for $n=1$ where the key step is: for $a,b,c\in G$ we have $$(ab)c=acb[b,c]=ca[a,c]b[b,c]=c(ab)[a,c]^b[b,c]$$ which imply $$[ab,c]=[a,c]^b[b,c].$$ It can easly seen to impmly the case $n=1$.
I struggle to prove it for $n\geq 2$, and will be happy for some help.

This is true. It is proposition 1.3.6 in McKay's p Groups notes. The idea is to use induction, and to show (via commutator identities) that if a normal subgroup $N\lhd G$ is normally generated by $T$, then $[N,G]=\langle [t_i,s_j]\rangle^G$.

Yes this is true.
Let $N = \langle [s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_n]^x \mid s_i \in S, x \in G \rangle$.
For $n=1$, note that the images of all pairs of generators in $G/N$ commute, so $G/N$ is abelian, and hence $[G,G] \le N$.
For $n>1$, we use induction on $n$ and assume that the result is true for all smaller values of $n$.
By considering the generators with $x=1_G$, we see that the images in $G/N$ of all generates in $S$ commute with the images of all elements $[s_0,\ldots,s_{n-1}]$. Hence the image of each such element lies in $Z(G/N)$, and hence so does the normal closure in $G/N$ of the group generated by all such elements.
But by our inductive hypothesis, that normal closure is equal to $\gamma_{n-1}(G)$, so the image of $\gamma_{n-1}(G)$ lies in $Z(G/N)$, which is equivalent to $\gamma_n(G) = [\gamma_{n-1}(G),G] \le N$.
